# Translate Curl to Ruby (New Relic API)

Tags: ruby, curl, newrelic

I am extremly new to ruby, but I am playing around with it. Could someone help me translate this curl command to Ruby ?

I have been having a difficult time trying to adapt other ruby examples to fit my needs.

```
  curl -X GET 'https://api.newrelic.com/v2/servers.json' \
     -H 'X-Api-Key:12345689' -i \
     -G -d 'filter[host]=server1'
```

Ruby Code:

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI.parse('https://api.newrelic.com/v2/servers.json')
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
     :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') {|http| http.request request}

request.initialize_http_header({'X-Api-Key' => '12345689'})
request.initialize_http_header({'Accept' => 'application/json'})
request.initialize_http_header({'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
request.set_form_data({"filter[host]" => "server1"})


response = res.request(request)
```

Error Message:

```
test.rb:16:in `<main>': undefined method `request' for #<Net::HTTPUnauthorized 401 Unauthorized readbody=true> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: What problem do you face? Is there an error message? Can you please post your attempt.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code translation service.

Comment: @spickermann
Sorry Im a linux admin, Busy playing around with stuff, I put my ruby code in but I have no idea about anything ruby really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should look something like this:

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI('https://api.newrelic.com/v2/servers.json')
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form({ 'filter[host]' => 'server1' })
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
req['X-Api-Key'] = '123456789'

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.hostname, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
response =  http.request(req)
p response.read_body
```

Comment: Hey man, Thanks for you answer, I have tried your code and get the following error.
`/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `read_nonblock': end of file reached (EOFError) `

Comment: ah that's usually an ssl issue - I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, you can simply get the output of a command by using backticks (`` ` ``), you only had to escape the special characters, like in every other string. So it would be:

```
`curl -X GET 'https://api.newrelic.com/v2/servers.json' -H 'X-Api-Key:12345689' -i -G -d 'filter[host]=server1'`
```